# Не работает SCSS с условием :hover

Tags: html, css, jade, scss

Должен цветить и без линии под текстом

```
a(href='#')
  p.small-grey-text.link US Politics
```

```
p.link {
  color: $smallGrey;
  text-decoration: none; 

  &:hover {
    color: $hoverTitle;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб убрать подчеркивание `text-decoration` нужно ставить не на параграф, а на ссылку `а`. Изменять цвет также правильнее будет на ссылке, но будет работать и так:

```css
a, a:hover {
  text-decoration: none; 
}

p.link {
  color: #aaa;
  width: 100px;

  &:hover {
    color: #c00;
  }
}
```

**HO!** В данном случае я бы посоветовал избавиться от элемента `р` - он здесь лишний со всех сторон. Я полагаю, что Вы его добавили из-за его свойств блокового элемента (`margin`, `padding`  и т.д.), но это легко навешивается на саму ссылку. Код получается и чище, и правильнее:

```
a(href='#').small-grey-text.link US Politics

a.link {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;

  &:hover {
    color: #c00;
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjxBGv)

Answer (score 0):

а почему не сделать так?

jade

```
a(href='#').small-grey-text.link US Politics
```

css

```
a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  &:hover {
    color: #c00;
  }
}
```

или же
scss

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  p {
    &.link {
      color: #aaa;
      width: 100px;
      &:hover {
        color: #c00;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

jade

```
a(href='#')
  p.small-grey-text.link US Politics
```

- хотя на р не желательно вешать классы